# System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider, simplemembership

Is it possible to get the password of a user? How, please? When I've tried this code :

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("nectarys-pc.MonitoringN.dbo", "Superviseur", "UserId", "matricule", autoCreateTables: true);
var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
model.motDePasse = membership.GetUser(superviseur.matricule, false).GetPassword();
```

This exception appears in the last line :

> System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.

How to deal this?

**Note** that `superviseur.matricule` is not the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per MSDN - 
[If EnablePasswordRetrieval in web.config is false, a NotSupportedException exception is thrown.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.getpassword.aspx)

Check this resource to find out how to [set enablePasswordReset in Web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.enablepasswordretrieval%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm using simpleMembershipr provider. I can't find it into my `web.config`. How do I to add it, please?

Comment: @user3278631, updated my answer with one more resource.

Comment: That's for `EnablePasswordReset`.

Comment: @user3278631, Google took me to wrong location. I updated to correct location now.

Answer (score 1):

Checking [MSDN for GetPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.getpassword%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) shows you that it throws the `System.NotSupportedException` when *"[EnablePasswordRetrieval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.enablepasswordretrieval%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) is false."*

You can change EnablePasswordRetrieval in your web.config

Comment: I'm using SimpleMembershipr provider. I can't find it into my `web.config`. How do I to add it, please?