# Specified method is not supported. with method MembershipUser.GetPassword()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I get the following error:

> ## Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> ### Specified method is not supported.
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not >supported.

**Source Error:**

```
Line 109:            modelo.apellido = usuario.apellido;
Line 110:            modelo.nombre = usuario.nombre;
-->Line 111:         modelo.clave = Membership.GetUser(usuario.userName).GetPassword();<--
Line 112:
Line 113:            return PartialView(modelo);
```

This is my Web.Config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider"
         type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"
         connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="true" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         passwordFormat="Encrypted"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
         applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" 
         type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" 
         connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" 
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

[I tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827196/system-notsupportedexception-specified-method-is-not-supported) but when I debug, the enablePasswordRetrieval property of the Membership class is set to "false".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(usuario.userName, false);
modelo.clave = u.GetPassword();
```

Comment: Doing that gets me the same error I had before. Again on the GetPassword method. I think it's probably a config issue, since when I debug the ennablePasswordRetrieval is still set to "false" even though I set it to "true" on the Web.Config file.